# Can a string from the user (such as a paragraph) be imported/inputted into PyGame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

I am creating a program that needs to accept a string (such as a paragraph) from the user, then display certain words from that string in a larger font. Would I use PyGame for this? I know text can be put on the screen with PyGame, but I am having difficulty storing the input from the user. I am using Sublime 3 with SublimeREPL, and when I take user input, REPL says it can not run with Python. Can user input be acquired without SublimeREPL, such as directly with PyGame? If not, how would I go about making the program as described above?

I am new to programming, so I apologize for any misunderstandings. Any and all help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: first: run it without Sublime and SublimeREPL. Run `python your_script.py`. Users will do the same.

Comment: Thank you so much! However, what do you mean when you say I should run it without Sublime? Do you mean on a seperate development program?

Comment: Sublime it only editor/IDE to create program but after you create it you will run it without any editor/IDE. So test it without any editor/IDE. Run it directly in terminal/cmd.exe/etc. BTW: Chrome/Firefox probaly was developed with Visual Studio (or other IDE) but you don't use Visual Studio to run it.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

First: run it without Sublime and SublimeREPL. Run `python your_script.py`. Users will do the same.

---

If you need only one input then you can

1. run script with parameters `python your_script.py "some text"`,
2. use `input()` in Python to get text before it will run `PyGame`.

But these methods need terminal (text window) and don't look nice when you create graphics program.

---

`PyGame` doesn't have widgets to get text from user. There are modules which can add some widgets but you have to learn how to build PyGame application with widgets because they may need to respect some rules.

See [GUI on page PyGame.org](https://www.pygame.org/tags/gui)
(ie. [OcempGUI](https://www.pygame.org/project/125))

---

You can try to build own widget to get text. You can use key event to get text, update text in list (add or remove char) and use text from list to update text in window. [Text Input](https://www.pygame.org/project-Pygame+Text+Input-3013-.html)

---

Some people use `Tkinter` to display window which ask for text. Or they embed `PyGame` in Tkinter's window with other widgets.